# Making a chess matrix

Tags: r, matrix

So I'm using r and I'd like to make a code that takes a value of n, creates a n x n matrix that has alternating 1's and 0's.

E.g:
[image]

I can't seem to do this without getting an error or warning and it won't work for all integers of n, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not really recommended but it works: `suppressWarnings(matrix(1:0, n, n))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this?

```
n <- 5L

matrix(seq(1:n^2) %% 2, nrow = n)  
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    1    0
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks, didn't think of using a sequence

Comment: Nice answer! A bit shorter one might be  `seq(n^2)` if you like code-golfing .) Upvoted yours, +1!

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding.  I wasn't aware that seq() worked without even providing the start value.  Thanks for the update. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below

```
m <- matrix(rep_len(c(1, 0), n^2), n)
```

or

```
m <- replace(m <- diag(n), !((row(m) - col(m)) %% 2), 1)
```

which gives

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    1    0
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1
```