# How do I produce a chess/chessboard matrix of 1's and 0's in R without typing it all out?

Tags: r, matrix, chess

I have an identical issue to the one shown here (i.e., making an alternating matrix of 1's and 0's):

[Making a chess matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239900/making-a-chess-matrix)

My issue is that nobody answering the question seemed to check what happens when using an even number of rows/columns, such as, for example, the normal sized chessboard (i.e., 8 x 8).

Is there a straightforward solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try

```
f <- function(n) {
    m <- matrix(seq(1:n^2) %% 2, nrow = n)
    if (!n %% 2) {
        idx <- !seq_len(n) %% 2
        m[, idx] <- 1 - m[, idx]
    }
    m
}
```

or

```
f <- function(n) {
    sapply(1:n, \(k) (!k %% 2) - (-1)^k * rep_len(c(1, 0), n))
}
```

such that

```
> f(3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    1

> f(4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    1

> f(5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    1    0
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1

> f(6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    0    1    0    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[5,]    1    0    1    0    1    0
[6,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
```